# How to use google apps script to duplicate a new google sheet while preserving the conditional formatting?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

[image]

Hi everyone,

I have a google sheet with 2 tabs inside. The data are all come from another google sheet by using `Importrange` formula. I want to duplicate this google sheet by using google apps script while preserving the conditional formatting but at the same time remove the `Importrange` formula. In other words, there should be no `Importrange` formula in the duplicated sheet but still have all the formatting and data. Is there any way I can achieve my goal? There are some similar questions on internet but did not perform exactly what I want. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

The logic is the following:

- Duplicate the sheets in the original spreadsheet file so the conditional formatting is maintained and copy paste the values so the importrange disappears.
- Create a new spreadsheet file and put it in the same folder as the original one and copy the sheets of the original spreadsheet file to the newly created one.
- Delete the duplicate sheets in the original spreadsheet file.
- Update (the name of the new spreadsheet file is given by the cell E2 of the original spreadsheet (1st sheet).

### Solution:

```
function duplicateSpreadsheet() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const ssid = ss.getId();
  const folderId = DriveApp.getFileById(ssid).getParents().next().getId();
  const title = ss.getSheetByName("Data1").getRange("E2").getDisplayValue(); //added
  const new_ss = SpreadsheetApp.create(title);
  const dest_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  DriveApp.getFileById(new_ss.getId()).moveTo(dest_folder);
  const sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sh=>{
      let shDup = sh.copyTo(ss);
      shDup.getDataRange().setValues(shDup.getDataRange().getValues());
      shDup.copyTo(new_ss).setName(sh.getName());
      ss.deleteSheet(shDup);
  });
    new_ss.deleteSheet(new_ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"));
}
```

Comment: Hi soMario, thanks for your reply. But I think you misunderstand my question. I want to duplicate the entire spreadsheet (consist of two tabs, `Data1` & `Data2`) and located in the same google drive folder. What your code does is duplicating one tab in the google sheet.  Do you have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: @weizer I updated my answer. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I tried your code, but it only duplicated the tabs within the spreadsheet instead of creating another new one

Comment: I saw you are using `SpreadsheetApp.create("Dup Spreadsheet")` but not sure why it doesn't work

Comment: @weizer sorry I just updated my code again, now it should be 100% correct. I create it in the same folder as your original spreadsheet and I also delete the duplicate sheets generated in the source file. Please try again the new code and let me know if it works.

Comment: thank you so much, it works perfectly now! Is it possible to automate the name for the duplicated sheet so that it is based on the text in cell E2 in google sheet? I tried `SpreadsheetApp.create(getCell(2,5))` & `SpreadsheetApp.create().getCell(2,5)` but both doesn't work

Comment: Stackoverflow does not allow for follow up questions but I will make an exception, you want to change the title of the duplicate spreadsheet file according to which sheet of the original spreadsheet file ? Data1 or Data2 ? @weizer

Comment: Thanks @soMario, just `Data1` will do